# HTML form calculation system

Tags: javascript, html

I know that this might be simple, but I was trying to create some sort of system in HTML using Javascript, that when you input a number in the input tag it multiplies it with another number, them outputs the number in another input tag. But for some strange reason, I can't really find out how to do it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var test = document.getElementById('input');

        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('output').value = test + 20;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Input: <input id="input">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <br><br>

    <input id="output" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Btw, I don't know how to use JQuery or those types of things, so could you write it in simple HTML?

Comment: You only ever define `test` once - and even that is before the element has actually loaded. So how do you expect that to work? You want to get the value *inside* the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `value` property of an input rather than `innerHTML`:
Also use `parseInt` so that you can sum the numbers as `input.value` will be a string.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('output').value = parseInt(test.value, 10) + 20;
}
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason every time I input a number the output is always NaN (not a number)

Comment: are you sure you are adding numbers? It's very possible that you aren't and that's why you get NaN, like if you sum undefined and a number... Check that you are referring correctly to the values and that you use parseInt on them. Use console.log to check things are happening as expected

Comment: I don't know what happened, but in the end it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/1uv9cqys/8/

```js
 function myFunction() {
  var test = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('output').value = parseInt(test) * 20;
}
```

```html
    Input: <input id="input" type="number">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <br><br>

    Final : <input id="output" type="text">
```

Comment: @JohnDoe Please accept this an answer so other member can benefit as well from this solution.